# Grouping only consecutive elements based on property using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list of objects, each object having an id. I want to group elements by their id given they are consecutive. Like, if objects are:

```
(id1, id1, id1, id2, id2, id3, id3, id2, id2, id4)
```

then groups must be:

```
(id1, id1, id1), (id2, id2), (id3, id3), (id2, id2), (id4)
```

Can this be achieved by Java Streams API?

Comment: The expected output is a `List<List<ObjectName>>` or `Map<Long, List<ObjectName>>`

Comment: Hint: `objects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjectName::getId))`

Comment: But this would group together all  elements with same id even if they are not consecutive. What I want is that they are grouped only if they are consecutive and have same id.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I don't read your question correctly, in this case, I guess using stream can be bad, a simple for loop can do the job for you.

Comment: Why this downvote?

Comment: Not the down-voter ;)

Comment: Actually, this is a very interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very possible using mutable reduction resulting in the `List<List<String>>`. For better readability, I recommend to split into methods:

```
List<List<String>> newList = list.stream().collect(
    ArrayList::new,
    (lists, string) -> {
        if (lists.isEmpty()) {
            withNewList(lists, string);
        } else {
            withNewString(lists, string);
        }
    },
    ArrayList::addAll
);
```

```
// adds a new inner list with a single item (string)
static void withNewList(ArrayList<List<String>> lists, String string) {
    List<String> newList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    newList1.add(string);
    lists.add(newList1);
}
```

```
static void withNewString(ArrayList<List<String>> lists, String string) {
    // if the last inserted list has a same item
    List<String> lastList = lists.get(lists.size() - 1);   
    if (lastList.contains(string)) {
        // append it to the last inner list
        lastList.add(string);
    } else {
        // or else create a new list with a single item (string)
        withNewList(lists, string);
    }
}
```

Considering the following `list` input:

```
List<String> list = List.of(
    "id1", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id3", "id3", "id2", "id2", "id4");
```

... when you print the result out, the output looks like:

> `[[id1, id1, id1], [id2, id2], [id3, id3], [id2, id2], [id4]]`

Answer (score 0):

For easy navigation to the last (previous) item, I'd use a LinkedList of LinkedLists:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    Stream.of(id1, id1, id1, id2, id2, id3, id3, id2, id2, id4)
            .sequential() // order is essential
            .collect(LinkedList::new, (listOfLists, object) -> {
        if (listOfLists.isEmpty() || listOfLists.getLast().getLast() != object) {
            listOfLists.add(new LinkedList<>(List.of(object)));
        } else {
            listOfLists.getLast().add(object);
        }
    }, List::addAll);
    ...
}
```